# willDisplayCell first row does not work in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I wanted to make custom corner rounded background for my custom cells and it worked with code below but the first row is not affected I should scroll it up to make it have a background

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row != 0 {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            var whiteRoundedCornerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 365, 250))
            whiteRoundedCornerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
            whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.masksToBounds = false
            whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
            whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-0, -1)
            whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1

            cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedCornerView)
            cell.contentView.sendSubviewToBack(whiteRoundedCornerView)
        }


    }
```

Comment: Why do you have `if indexPath.row != 0`?

Comment: In that case, I'll post it as an answer so that other people can see that the question has been solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code is the `if` statement. When `indexPath.row` is 0 (which is the first row), your configuration code isn't executed. To solve this, simply remove the `if` statement from your code. It should look something like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    var whiteRoundedCornerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 365, 250))
    whiteRoundedCornerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-0, -1)
    whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1

    cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedCornerView)
    cell.contentView.sendSubviewToBack(whiteRoundedCornerView)
}
```